# Can I modify the header array in cakephp httpsocket request?

Tags: php, cakephp

I basically need to add a variable in the header array of a cakePHP socket request

This is not a query but a custom header variable expected by the webservice.
I have a variable 'Hash' that needs to be sent in the header and not as a query string inside my $HttpSocket->request in cakephp 2.0.

this is my request variable and its header array below:

```
 $request = array( 
                 'header' => array(
                        'Hash'=>$hash_key

                )       
         );
```

However a debug of the script shows the Hash variable is missing. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Custom request headers do work just fine. How are you creating and sending the actual request? How are you debugging it? And please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: I am working with CakePHP 2.5.2

Comment: Ok, but again, please show the actual code you are using for sending _and_ debugging, the pointer to `HttpSocket::request()` and the array snippet alone aren't of much use. Also your newly added info makes it a little unclear what exactly you are asking, ie whether things are currently not being sent at all, or whether they are unexpectedly sent in the query string?

Answer (score 1):

Oops so sorry guys. I figured it out, I was not passing the $request to my request. It was a silly mistake. sorry for wasting your precious time.

This is what I finally did.

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```

$response = $HttpSocket->get($URL,$query, $request);